# Cambiar de color a unas barras estadisticas con Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Hola necesito apoyo de como le puedo cambiar de color a las barras que estan abajo e tratato de cambiarlas pero no tengo resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo

```
$(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: baseurl + 'asistencia/traer_turnos',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data)
    {
        var bar = Morris.Bar({
            element: 'bar-chart',
            data: data,
            xkey: 'turno',
            ykeys: ['total_docentes', 'total_alumnos', 'docentes_faltantes', 'alumnos_faltantes'],
            labels: ['Total Docentes', 'Total Alumnos', 'Alumnos Faltantes', 'Docentes Faltantes'],
            fillColor: ['#0b62a4', '#D58665', '#FFFFFF', '#BC05FF'],
            hideHover: 'auto',
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Por favor utiliza el code snippet-[mira aquí cómo usarlo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430/78) para crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saludos

Comment: ¿Cambiar los valores de `fillColor` no funciona?

Comment: solo era 'barColors: ['#0b62a4', '#D58665', '#00ffd1', '#BC05FF'],'

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores , por favor, agrega el código resultante que indicas como una respuesta y márcala como respuesta correcta para poder dar por cerrada esta pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Solo era:

```
'barColors: ['#0b62a4', '#D58665', '#00ffd1', '#BC05FF'],'
```